# Creating a WCF Service Website

Tags: wcf, hosting

I am following Learning WCF by Michelle Bustamante for understanding in and out of WCF.
I am trying to create a WCF Service Web Site, following steps given in an example but I am getting error saying " Unable to create website XYZ. To acess local IIS Web sites, you must install the following IIS components. IIS6 metaBase and IIS6 Config Compatibility ASP.NET"

Am I missing something? I am using windows 7 as OS and VS 2010 as IDE. And the book follows VS 2005 with .NET 3.0...

Steps which I followed:
1. Start VS2010 as Amdin
2. File -> New Web Site -> WCF Service
3. Selected HTTP as location for new Site and entered path as 
4. Clicked OK
and Error popped Up.

Has this scenario changed since book got published??? Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the Control Panel, Programs and Features, Turn Windows features on or off, and then dig through the IIS checkboxes and check on the things its saying you're missing. In particular:

```
- Internet Information Services
  - Web Management Tools
    - IIS 6 Management Compatibility
      - IIS Metabase and IIS 6 configuration compatibility
```

Comment: @Larson: Thanks a lot. It is done and Error gone. But still have 1 more doubt. After creating a new website it showed me an informatory message as " AS.NEt 4.0 has not been registered on Web Server. You need to manually configure your web Server for ASP .NEt 4.0 in order for your site to run correctly". Can you explain to a bit about this?

Comment: I think you need to run the aspnet_regiis tool. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k6h9cz8h.aspx